# Gradle: zip files in jar task

Tags: gradle

I tried to zip files in the jar task but my Zip task is executed during gradle configuration phase. This is my simplified code:

```
task libZip(type: Zip) {  
     from configurations.runtime  
     archiveName 'lib.zip'  
     println "zip was created"
}  

jar {
     dependsOn libZip
    ... 
    doLast {
       // suggested place to zip files
   }
```

All works fine but the zip operation takes a "long" time. It should not be executed in configuration phase. Ok, no problem with a "doLast" in libZip task but I wanted the Zip file to be created when I do a "gradle :project:jar". I can`t get it to work to get both.

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by long? What is actually going wrong?

Comment: The task libZip is always executed (configuration phase) and that it takes too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I leave it like it is because the zip is not created in configuration phase (I thought so) but only the println "zip is created" was printed to console.